# Change in entropy of engine and the hot bath in a cycle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

I want to clarify that this question is not a homework-type question. I have provided its solution and the apparent discrepancy.

[image]

This is a question from a national competitive exam I gave. I am very confident that my answer is correct and the answer given in the answer key by the organizing institute is wrong. There is a provision to challenge the answer key which I did but they did not update their answer in the final answer key.

Their answer: (A),(C),(D) {more than one option can be correct}

My answer: (A), (D)

Justification for my answer:

$\Delta S= \Delta S_E+\Delta S_{Hb}=0+ \frac{\Delta Q}{T}= \frac{-Q_H}{T_H}=\frac{-750}{150}=-5$ J/K

As you can see, the answer is -5 J/K as opposed to 5 J/K so option (C) cannot be correct.

I wanted to know whether there could be some way by which their answer is more correct than mine?

Any flaw in my reasoning or understanding any terminology?

Comment: Is the term "change" has to including sign? like speed or velocity. It is a problem of wording, not physics. You have to consult literature people or legal person.

Comment: Yes, the word change implies it has to include sign. For instance, change in velocity can be positive or negative, while the magnitude of change in velocity ( which is speed) can only be positive. They haven't mentioned "magnitude" anywhere and since entropy is a physical quantity that can allow both positive and negative values, this discrepancy is not literary but pertains to Physics completely. In addition to that, the change in entropy of the Cold Bath is +5 J/K so you see that this is not a literary issue.

Comment: Please give feedback to OP rather than randomly downvoting.

Comment: @ytlu A change in entropy (internal energy, enthalpy, etc.) is plus, minus, or zero. If they meant the magnitude of the change then they should say "change in magnitude"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change in entropy of the hot bath has to be negative since heat transfers out of the bath. They are wrong.

I also object to them calling this engine a Carnot engine. A Carnot engine operates in a reversible cycle. The processes in a reversible cycle have to be carried out *very* slowly (quasi-statically). A 0.5 sec cycle is hardly a cycle carried out very slowly.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have yet not accepted it even though it's absolutely what I required. I am just keeping the question for other answers as well after which I will accept. Thanks a lot for the confirmation.

Comment: @Lost No problem, but beware of "institutions of experts". There is NO WAY the entropy of the hot bath can increase unless there is a hotter bath somewhere else transferring heat to it. For what it's worth I reported an error in thermodynamics once to MIT and they did nothing about it.

Comment: @Lost Another thing, sometimes the rationale for not correcting something on a test is if a person (like you) was erroneously marked wrong, so was everyone else, so the playing field is equal.

Comment: This rationale doesn't apply here because the people who have incorrectly marked option (C) along with (A) and (D) are getting unjustified marks. I have nothing against that. Its just that they have not even made this question invalid altogether. This is selective brutality. They have chosen to ignore the sign just because they like it. Thats the best thing you can do probably against mathematical correctness.

Comment: @Lost I've added another objection to this exam question.

Comment: Bravo. Your objection is hilarious because it so damn on point.  Very disappointing that they have overlooked such details.

Comment: I also lost 2 marks due to this confusion.

Comment: Hi Bob. I have found no way to set this right. I have emailed the department and others but to no avail . Do you have any advice in regards to how to deal with such institutions or is there nothing that can be done?

Comment: @Lost  I think you are dealing with an entrenched bureaucracy. If I were you I would not waste any more time dealing with them and move on.  The responses you have gotten  from your peers on this site have validated your position. That's all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you!

Carnot cycle calculations requires two axioms: energy is conserved and entropy is conserved. It also requires a boundary and a **sign convention** on the direction of the heat and entropy flows.

There is a problem with their question it’s the sign convention. They appear to **define work as positive** but given their “correct” answers they seems to define the heat flux from the hot body as positive too.

They must choose a consistent sign for fluxes crossing the boundary. Let’s assume the work is positive convention. This means that heat flowing out of the engine are positive and heat flowing into the engine is negative.

We are given the information that in **one cycle** $W=250 J$ and that $T_1=150K$ and $T_2=100K$.

It’s a little unclear from the question, but they are defining the heat in and out **per cycle** rather than the rate (I usually use rates hence the dots on my symbols in the diagram).

$$
Q_H + Q_L + 250 = 0\\
Q_H/150 + Q_L/100 = 0
$$

Therefore $Q_H=-750J$ and $Q_L=500J$.

**A**

A is correct in magnitude, but wrong in sign. Assume we define work as positive is should be -750J.

**B**

B is incorrect.

**C**

I really don’t know what mean, “entropy change of the engine”. It seems to contradict axiom 2 (entropy conservation). If they mean “what is the entropy flow from the hot body in one cycle” then this is just $-750/150=-5J/K$ (again assuming the work is positive sign convention).

**D**

D is correct because it’s an axiom.

[image: Carnot cycle]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I would like to point out that option (C) does not contradict any axiom as per se and is incorrect exactly because of the wrong sign. The reason for this is that the entropy change of the whole thermodynamical system will be zero in this case. They are only asking about the entropy change of a sub-system. Hence 2nd Law is not violated since its reversible. Also, energy conservation is not violated as the heat that flows to the cold reservoir and the work done in a cycle add up to the heat that flows out of the hot bath.

Comment: I’ve been updating my answer! Just read.

Comment: Yes thank you. Can you also please upvote? Someone has downvoted it and it might not receive views from other readers.

Comment: Upvote deployed ,